# Google cloud vision batch process of large number of images using python

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

I am new to python and cloud vision.I need to label ~20k images.My code although does the work, needs lots of time to process.Is there a way I can be more efficient?Any help will be really appreciated

```
filename=[]
description=[]
score=[]
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        if  f.endswith('.jpg'):
            file_name=indir+'/'+f

            with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
                content = image_file.read()
            image = types.Image(content=content)
            response = client.label_detection(image=image)
            labels = response.label_annotations

            for label in labels:
                filename.append(f)
                description.append(label.description)
                score.append(label.score)

import pandas as pd

vision_op = pd.DataFrame(
    {'filename': filename,
     'description': description,
     'score': score
    })
```

Comment: i would like to know as well

Answer (score 1):

You could send the requests from multiple threads to speed it up.

You can also send multiple images in a single API call since annotate accepts [multiple AnnotateImageRequests](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate).